# How can I overlay a box plot over plots in r ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to overlay a box plot of the different variable of same unit (measured with each data point), for days 1 and 2 at times a and b (one box plot per sub block). Is there a way to do this in ggplot2?

```
tdata <- import ("plant_temperature.csv")
tdata$Distance <- as.factor(tdata$Distance )

p <- ggplot(data = tdata, aes( y=Temp ,x=Distance,color=Type)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_boxplot( aes(y = Ambient))

p + facet_grid(cols = vars(Time),rows = vars(Day))
```

The sample data:

```
"Day","Time","Type","Temp","Distance","Ambient"
"1",1,"a","s",5,"1",4.4
"2",1,"a","f",3.1,"2",6.3
"3",1,"a","s",5.9,"3",3.1
"4",1,"a","f",8.4,"4",2.5
"5",1,"a","s",5.5,"1",7.7
"6",1,"b","f",9.9,"2",7.1
"7",1,"b","s",2.2,"3",2.1
"8",1,"b","f",6.9,"4",5.1
"9",1,"b","s",2.9,"1",9.4
"10",2,"b","f",8.8,"2",5.7
"11",2,"a","s",0.6,"3",6.3
"12",2,"a","f",2.2,"4",4.9
"13",2,"a","s",3.1,"1",0.8
"14",2,"a","f",1.4,"2",6.5
"15",2,"a","s",4,"3",2.1
"16",2,"b","f",8.4,"4",1.6
"17",2,"b","s",5.2,"1",4.4
"18",2,"b","f",2.2,"2",7.9
"19",2,"b","s",7.9,"3",5.3
"20",2,"b","f",2.7,"4",5.2
```

Temperature measured at days 1 and 2 at times a and b with sensors f and s at distances 1 through 4:

[image: Temperature measured at days 1 and 2 at times a and b with sensors f and s at distances 1 through 4]

If I try adding 1 box plot per sub block, I end up getting 4 box plots per subblock.

Comment: That is very possible. Do you have any example data that we can use to make an example with?

Comment: Please, instead of reading the data from a file we do not have access to, create `tdata` in your example code directly. I will be able to answer if you do provide the data.

Comment: I added the data, I'm unsure of the format I should be posting it in.

I also found that I can add a boxplot on distance 5, which works quite well:

`p<-ggplot(data = tdata, aes( y=Temp ,x=Distance,color=Type))+geom_point() +geom_boxplot( aes(y = Ambient,x=5,color="green"))
p+facet_grid(cols = vars(Time),rows = vars(Day))`

Comment: If this code answers your question satisfactorily, you should the answer the question yourself here below, and get the credit for it. It is perfectly acceptable, even encouraged, to answer one's own question when possible as the idea is to build a bank questions and answers that will help others in the future.  You could also edit the question removing the reference to temperature, as whether the data are for temperature or not  does not affect the answer. I can help with polishing question and answer, but do enter the answer yourself as building a reputation can be useful.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Please let me know if I can make any further improvements!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks good to rather add the box plot on a separate x value:

[image: Box plot of several variable groups]

```
tdata$Distance <- as.factor(tdata$Distance )
p<-ggplot(data = tdata, aes( y=Temp ,x=Distance,color=Type))+geom_point() +geom_boxplot( aes(y = Ambient,x=5,color="Ambient"))
p+facet_grid(cols = vars(Time),rows = vars(Day))
```

Does someone know how I can change the legend symbols? Perhaps I should ask a separate question.

Comment: Here is a separate post relating to the symbols: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62510721/13756066)