# How can I change legend symbols (key glyphs) to match the plot symbols?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I plot data points in several groups, but then add a box plot of a different variable (same unit). See the image below. How can I change the symbols in the legend to match the symbols in the plot?

[image: Different groups of variables with different symbols]

The code:

```
p <- ggplot(data = tdata, aes( y=Temp ,x=Distance, color=Type)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_boxplot( aes(y = Ambient,x=5,color="Ambient"))
p + facet_grid(cols = vars(Time),rows = vars(Day))
```

The data:

```
structure(list(Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Time = c("a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b"), Type = c("s", "f", "s", "f", "s", "f", "s", 
"f", "s", "f", "s", "f", "s", "f", "s", "f", "s", "f", "s", "f"
), Temp = c(5, 3.1, 5.9, 8.4, 5.5, 9.9, 2.2, 6.9, 2.9, 8.8, 0.6, 
2.2, 3.1, 1.4, 4, 8.4, 5.2, 2.2, 7.9, 2.7), Distance = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L), Ambient = c(4.4, 6.3, 3.1, 2.5, 7.7, 7.1, 2.1, 5.1, 
9.4, 5.7, 6.3, 4.9, 0.8, 6.5, 2.1, 1.6, 4.4, 7.9, 5.3, 5.2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

F and S should be green and blue dotes respectively and Ambient must be a box plot symbol in the Legend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the symbol or glyph in the legend can be set for each geom via the argument `key_glyph`. For an overview of available glyphs see [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/draw_key.html). (Thanks to @Tjebo for pointing that out.)

However, with the `key_glyph` argument one sets the glpyh globally for the "whole" geom and legend, i.e. one can not have different glyphs for different groups.

To overcome this and get to the desired result my approach uses two legends instead which I "glue" together so that they look as one. This is achieved by adding a second legend and removing the spacing and margin of the legends via `theme()`.

To get a second legend I use the `fill` aes in `geom_boxplot` instead of `color`. To mimic a mapping on color I set the fill color to `white` via `scale_fill_manual` and adjust the fill guide via `guide_legend`. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = tdata, aes(y=Temp, x = Distance, color = Type)) + 
  geom_boxplot(data = tdata, aes(x = 5, y = Ambient, fill = "box"), color = scales::hue_pal()(3)[1]) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "white") +
  scale_color_manual(values = scales::hue_pal()(3)[2:3]) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Type", order = 1), color = guide_legend(title = NULL, order = 2)) +
  theme(legend.margin = margin(t = 0, b = 0), legend.spacing.y = unit(0, "pt"), legend.title = element_text(margin = margin(b = 10)))
p + facet_grid(cols = vars(Time),rows = vars(Day))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Just for posterity, one *can* change key glyphs -  easily globally, but not for each geom. https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/3236 (+1)

Comment: @Tjebo. Thx. That's what I meant. Should be more precise in my answer. (;